regextract first word after second newline in g.sheet
I need to extract the word Trilocale from a complex multiline text like this in a google sheets cell (including \n)
1/19 vetrina
199.000
Trilocale via Arnoldo Mondadori 89, Borgo Venezia, Verona

Tried
=regexextract(A18;"^.+\n.+\n.+\n(.*)")

but giving me the whole third line. I only need the first word after the third \n PLease help! thanks, Alex

You can use:
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^.+\n.+\n(.+?) ")


Another solution that doesn't use regex:
=+SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"
"),3)," ")


